# Comparison of Row Values Across Columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    > df<-data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,3,NA,NA),B=c(NA,5,2,6,4,8),C=c(NA,NA,2,NA,NA,8))
    > df
       A  B  C
    1  1 NA NA
    2  1  5 NA
    3  2  2  2
    4  3  6 NA
    5 NA  4 NA
    6 NA  8  8
```

I want to use the row values in this dataframe to create a 4th "D" column, based on the following 3 conditions: 1) if there is only one value in the row, then assign that value to column D; 2) if all of the values in the row are the same (excluding NAs), then assign that "same" value to column D; 2) if any values in the row are different (excluding NAs), then assign NA to column D. This would create a vector and dataframe that looks like this:

```
    > df$D<-c(1,NA,2,NA,4,8)
    > df
       A  B  C  D
    1  1 NA NA  1
    2  1  5 NA NA
    3  2  2  2  2
    4  3  6 NA NA
    5 NA  4 NA  4
    6 NA  8  8  8
```

Comment: I tried this: apply(df,1,function(x) if(anyDuplicated(x)) x[which.min(is.na(x))] else NA). It works in this instance, but assigns a "same" value instead of an "NA" if only two of the three row values are the same.

Comment: your "trial" code implies something possibly different from what you actually describe. Why would you use `which.min` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
apply(df, 1, function(y) {
  A <- unique(na.omit(y))
  ifelse(length(A) > 1, NA, A)
})
# [1]  1 NA  2 NA  4  8
```

I think this should satisfy your conditions, or at least give you a tip on how to get started.

Comment: +1 ! I would do the same thing except I would use `if` (  if(length(A) > 1)
    NA
  else A) and not `ifelse`.